# How to pass data of API from function to widget/drawer?

Tags: flutter, api

I have to pass data from an API function to widget, How can I pass the data?

The response of my API is as below.

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "user": {
    "user_id": "609cab2cd5b6c",
    "name": "Test User",
    "mobile": "9909413561",
    "email": "sunil@gmail.com",
    "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
    "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344",
    "location": "Bardoli",
    "avatar": "upload/avatar/609cab2cd5b6c609cb9205afef.png",
    "device_id": "y",
    "created_at": "2021-05-13",
    "updated_at": "2021-05-13"
  },
  "user_plan": {
    "order_id": "1630562288613067f0604e217940396609cab2cd5b6c",
    "plan_id": "5d1de239d1045",
    "plan_name": "Free Trial",
    "access_level": "s",
    "total": "0",
    "validity": "7",
    "validity_type": "days",
    "material": "0",
    "video": "0",
    "quiz": "1",
    "valid_from": "2021-09-02",
    "valid_to": "2021-09-09",
    "transaction_date": "2021-09-02 11:28:08",
    "active": "1"
  },
  "standard": {
    "standard_id": "5d1594e283e1a",
    "standard_name": "Std 2",
    "active": "1"
  },
  "medium": {
    "medium_id": "5d15938aa1344",
    "medium_name": "English Medium",
    "active": "1"
  }
}
```

The Model Class which I created from above response as below in **login_model.dart** file.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final loginModel = loginModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

LoginModel loginModelFromJson(String str) =>
    LoginModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String loginModelToJson(LoginModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class LoginModel {
  LoginModel({
    required this.success,
    required this.user,
    required this.userPlan,
    required this.standard,
    required this.medium,
  });

  int success;
  LogedinUser user;
  UserPlan userPlan;
  UserStandard standard;
  UserMedium medium;

  factory LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LoginModel(
        success: json["success"],
        user: LogedinUser.fromJson(json["user"]),
        userPlan: UserPlan.fromJson(json["user_plan"]),
        standard: UserStandard.fromJson(json["standard"]),
        medium: UserMedium.fromJson(json["medium"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "success": success,
        "user": user.toJson(),
        "user_plan": userPlan.toJson(),
        "standard": standard.toJson(),
        "medium": medium.toJson(),
      };
}

class UserMedium {
  UserMedium({
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.mediumName,
    required this.active,
  });

  String mediumId;
  String mediumName;
  String active;

  factory UserMedium.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserMedium(
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
        mediumName: json["medium_name"],
        active: json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "medium_id": mediumId,
        "medium_name": mediumName,
        "active": active,
      };
}

class UserStandard {
  UserStandard({
    required this.standardId,
    required this.standardName,
    required this.active,
  });

  String standardId;
  String standardName;
  String active;

  factory UserStandard.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserStandard(
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        standardName: json["standard_name"],
        active: json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "standard_name": standardName,
        "active": active,
      };
}

class LogedinUser {
  LogedinUser({
    required this.userId,
    required this.name,
    required this.mobile,
    required this.email,
    required this.standardId,
    required this.mediumId,
    required this.location,
    required this.avatar,
    required this.deviceId,
    required this.createdAt,
    required this.updatedAt,
  });

  String userId;
  String name;
  String mobile;
  String email;
  String standardId;
  String mediumId;
  String location;
  String avatar;
  String deviceId;
  DateTime createdAt;
  DateTime updatedAt;

  factory LogedinUser.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => LogedinUser(
        userId: json["user_id"],
        name: json["name"],
        mobile: json["mobile"],
        email: json["email"],
        standardId: json["standard_id"],
        mediumId: json["medium_id"],
        location: json["location"],
        avatar: json["avatar"],
        deviceId: json["device_id"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "user_id": userId,
        "name": name,
        "mobile": mobile,
        "email": email,
        "standard_id": standardId,
        "medium_id": mediumId,
        "location": location,
        "avatar": avatar,
        "device_id": deviceId,
        "created_at":
            "${createdAt.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${createdAt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${createdAt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "updated_at":
            "${updatedAt.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${updatedAt.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${updatedAt.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
      };
}

class UserPlan {
  UserPlan({
    required this.orderId,
    required this.planId,
    required this.planName,
    required this.accessLevel,
    required this.total,
    required this.validity,
    required this.validityType,
    required this.material,
    required this.video,
    required this.quiz,
    required this.validFrom,
    required this.validTo,
    required this.transactionDate,
    required this.active,
  });

  String orderId;
  String planId;
  String planName;
  String accessLevel;
  String total;
  String validity;
  String validityType;
  String material;
  String video;
  String quiz;
  DateTime validFrom;
  DateTime validTo;
  DateTime transactionDate;
  String active;

  factory UserPlan.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => UserPlan(
        orderId: json["order_id"],
        planId: json["plan_id"],
        planName: json["plan_name"],
        accessLevel: json["access_level"],
        total: json["total"],
        validity: json["validity"],
        validityType: json["validity_type"],
        material: json["material"],
        video: json["video"],
        quiz: json["quiz"],
        validFrom: DateTime.parse(json["valid_from"]),
        validTo: DateTime.parse(json["valid_to"]),
        transactionDate: DateTime.parse(json["transaction_date"]),
        active: json["active"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "order_id": orderId,
        "plan_id": planId,
        "plan_name": planName,
        "access_level": accessLevel,
        "total": total,
        "validity": validity,
        "validity_type": validityType,
        "material": material,
        "video": video,
        "quiz": quiz,
        "valid_from":
            "${validFrom.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${validFrom.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${validFrom.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "valid_to":
            "${validTo.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${validTo.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${validTo.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "transaction_date": transactionDate.toIso8601String(),
        "active": active,
      };
}
```

The Function which I created as below, Here I got all data from Model class perfectly.

The Function is created in **api_manager.dart** file.

```
Future userLogin(
    context,
    String mobile,
    String standardId,
    String mediumId,
  ) async {
    final String loginUrl = "$baseUrl/user/login";

    var formData = FormData.fromMap({
      'mobile': mobile,
      'standard_id': standardId,
      'medium_id': mediumId,
    });
    var response = await dio.post(loginUrl, data: formData);
    final logedinUserData = loginModelFromJson(response.data);
    final LogedinUser userData = logedinUserData.user;
    final status = logedinUserData.success;
    //print(logedinUserData.user.name);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var res = response.data;
      print("Response:=> " + res);
      print(status);
    } else {
      print('Failed to login.');
    }
  }
```

And Here is my Drawer code which I placed in **drawer.dart** file.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDrawer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyDrawerState createState() => _MyDrawerState();
}

class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
  final imageUrl = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: Container(
        //color: Colors.deepPurple,
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [
                  const Color(0xFFee436e),
                  const Color(0xFFF37D71),
                ])),
                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                accountName: Text("Dhaval Chaudhari"),
                accountEmail: Text("dhaval@gmail.com"),
                currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(imageUrl),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So here I have to display **User Name and Email** in drawer so how can I pass the data from function to drawer?

Comment: return data from the function and call the function inside drawer.dart, assign the value to a variable and you will have access to that data in the widget.

Comment: `void initState() {
    super.initState();

    ApiManager()
        .userLogin(context, mobile, standardId, mediumId)
        .then((userData) {
      setState(() {
        _userData = userData;
        print(_userData);
      });
    });
  }`     Like this?

Comment: I try this but when i open the drawer it throws error  --> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Comment: Have you considered putting this into a `FutureBuilder`?

Comment: No, let me try.

Comment: But your error is likely caused by having a required field in your model without assigning any value to it. If you have nullable data, declare member like `String?` instead of `String`.